# Add button to Android's copy/paste bar to all applications

Tags: android, copy, selection, copy-paste, paste

I would like to add a button to the "selection bar".

[image]

that would be present in all applications - or, in other words, I would like to modify the default buttons of this bar.

I've searched for it, however, it seems to me that most solutions are about modifying the bar of a specific app. For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892661/interface-from-text-selection-tool-where-copy-paste-is) - but I am not sure if the question is about the general modification that I want to do and I don't want to change the [context menu](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/cm2.png), but the "selection bar".

So, is it possible to modify this bar? If yes, could someone please provide links/examples for the same.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the text selection handle for your app by many ways, create [contextual](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu) menu of your own is probably the best among them.

This is the Android reference [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts) for creating custom components.

But this is limited to your app only and other apps or Android device itself won't be using this design. I really doubt that you can change this using your app as then it would be overriding the OS design itself.